# Why can I not write every $N \times M$ matrix as multiplication of an $N \times 1$ and a $1 \times M$ matrix?

Tags: matrices

My intuition says I simply can't express $N \times M$ independent variables in terms of $N+M$ variables but how can I show that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hint: [Rank decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization).

Comment: Or, just use the fact that $\textrm{rank } (AB) \leq \min\{\textrm{rank } A, \textrm{rank } B\}$, which could be proved with this decomposition.